# How to run PyQt4 app in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt4

I tried to run a PyQt4 app, but got following error:

> cannot connect to X server :0.0

It seems i need to install the "X server", what's this?
How to install it easily? I am using Linode VPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-server(xf86,xorg etc) is graphical subsystem for unix-like operating systems.
On ubunty you can install xorg with command

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

If you use another os you should use it's package management system, e.g. yum on centos, redhat etc.

**EDIT**: Since you need GUI next you could want to do is install graphical desktop environment( i propose **xfce**), desktop manager(i think it will be installed with desktop environment, but just in case there are **xdm**, **gdm**, **kdm**). This will allow you to start X-server on machine startup and use graphical login. I don't know exactly what tools Linode gives you to access server. If you have something like IP-KVM that's all you need. If not, you'll have to install VNC-server, set it up and start it. Then you will be able to connect to your Linode server with VNC-client and log into your machine in graphic mode.

Comment: After install xorg, i still got the error: cannot connect to X server.

Comment: You need to start x server. On desktop machine you can use **startx** command, it will start x-server and enter graphical mode.  But i do not know how it will apear on Linode vps.  Usually you don't need graphical environment on your server.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to run a Python script which uses PyQt4(PyQt4.QtGui).

Comment: If you need GUI, you probably have to install graphical environment and desktop manager. I'll edit answer.